Compute elliptic integral in special case
Dear Math Enthusiasts and Experts, Could you give me some hints, useful references or just express the integral
$$
\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2\cos^2{(t)}}{\sqrt{\sin^4{(t)}-b\sin^2{t}+c}}\, dt
$$
in terms of elliptic functions for the case $b^2-4c<0$, $b>0$, $c>0$? This integral originates from
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-s}}{\sqrt{s(s^2-bs+c)}}\,ds=\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1-s}{\sqrt{s(1-s)(s^2-bs+c)}}\,ds\,.
$$
The complicated formula (which includes a couple of more formulas :)) from P. Byrd "Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists" I.259.00 and I.259.03 for m=1 seems to be misleading. Maple 17 computes the second indefinite integral but has problems to compute the limit at s=1. Mathematica 12.0 also fails.
Many Thanks in advance!
Piotr
